# SFINAE to detect operation when it is forbidden to call with temporary

Tags: c++, sfinae, detection-idiom

It is possible to use the following pattern to detect whether or not x can be applied to T

```
template<class T, class Enable = void>
struct CanDoX: std::false_type{};

template<class T>
struct CanDoX<T, std::void_t<decltype(x(std::declval<T>()))>>:std::true_type{};
```

What if `x` has been defined as

```
Foo const& x(Bar const&&) = delete;
Foo const& x(Bar const& val) 
    {return val.get();}
```

Now `CanDoX<Bar>::value` is `false`, because no overload accepts a temporary. Somehow, there has to be a `Bar val` before the test for `x(val)`.

Comment: So, is this code working or not?  It's not clear to me exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @NathanOliver Make CanDoX correctly detect the permitted overload.

Comment: _Somehow, there has to be a Bar val before the test for x(val)_ - isn't that what `std::declval<T>()` does?

Comment: Do you want `std::declval<const T&>()` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, that worked. You may write that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::declval<T>()` returns a `T&&` so the better match is `Foo const& x(Bar const&&)`.

but you can use lvalue reference inside `std::declval` to get lvalue:

```
template<class T>
struct CanDoX<T, std::void_t<decltype(x(std::declval<T&>()))>>:std::true_type{};
```

or

```
template<class T>
struct CanDoX<T, std::void_t<decltype(x(std::declval<const T&>()))>>:std::true_type{};
```

Depending of your needs.